# Unable to Access Store and Dispatch from Redux Middleware

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-middleware

I am trying to create a simple Redux middleware in my React Redux Electron app that uses Thunk and `connected-react-router`.

In `myMiddleware.js`, we need to access the Redux store and `dispatch` function to send some actions. However, `getState` and `dispatch` are `undefined` as shown in the code below.

What is the correct way to access both of them in a custom Redux middleware?

**Github Repo:** 
https://github.com/nyxynyx/accessing-store-dispatch-from-redux-middleware

**middleware/myMiddleware.js**

```
const myMiddleware = () => {
    return ({ getState, dispatch }) => {
        console.log(getState)       // undefined
        console.log(dispatch)       // undefined

        return next => action => {
            return next(action);
        }
    }
}
```

**store.js**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers, compose } from 'redux';
import { connectRouter, routerMiddleware, push } from 'connected-react-router';
import persistState from 'redux-localstorage';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import myMiddleware from './middleware/myMiddleware';

export default function configureStore(initialState, routerHistory) {
    const router = routerMiddleware(routerHistory);

    const actionCreators = {
      push,
    };

    const reducers = {
      router: connectRouter(routerHistory),
    };

    const middlewares = [myMiddleware, thunk, router];

    const composeEnhancers = (() => {
      const compose_ = window && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__;
      if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' && compose_) {
        return compose_({ actionCreators });
      }
      return compose;
    })();

    const enhancer = composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middlewares), persistState());
    const rootReducer = combineReducers(reducers);

    return createStore(rootReducer, initialState, enhancer);
 }
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router';
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';
import routes from './routes';
import configureStore from './store';

const syncHistoryWithStore = (store, history) => {
  const { router } = store.getState();
  if (router && router.location) {
    history.replace(router.location);
  }
};

const initialState = {};
const routerHistory = createMemoryHistory();
const store = configureStore(initialState, routerHistory);
syncHistoryWithStore(store, routerHistory);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={routerHistory}>{routes}</ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Using

- connected-react-router@6.8.0
- react-dom@16.13.1
- react-redux@7.2.0
- react-router-dom@5.1.2
- react-router@5.1.2
- react@16.13.1
- redux-localstorage@0.4.1
- redux-thunk@2.3.0
- redux@4.0.5
- Node v14.0.0